# Erro: "unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied" quando não se usa SUDO

Tags: git, linux

Eu utilizei aquele comando `git config --global credential.helper cache` para armazenar o cache do login no bitbucket quando faço o `git pull` em produção.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente quando uso o comando `sudo git pull`, porém eu gostaria de usar sem o `sudo`, já que as permissões dos arquivos baixados estão ficando como `root`.

Porém, ao fazer o comando sem usar `sudo`, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied

Imagino que isso tenha relação com alguma pasta que o `git` está sem permissão para escrever sem usar `sudo` antes.

Como resolver isso?

O sistema operacional que eu estou usando é o *Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente, o problema é com permissão de pastas.

Basta rodar o seguinte comando para resolver:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.git-credential-cache/
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to run the following command and it works. 

    chmod 0700 /home/<user>/.git-credential-cache